# How to force installation of kernel updates when using apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, kernel, upgrade, package-management

To update my server I use `apt-get upgrade`.

But when there are kernel updates I always need to do `apt-get install linux-....` because `apt-get update` does not install them.

Is there a way I can tell it to install those too? I tried -f but it does not work.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` installs new kernels for me if there is one. What Ubuntu version are you using? The only thing I have up to check right now is 10.04...

Comment: 10.04 also, it tells me "These updates are kept from being upgraded" (translated from French). and it lists the linux updates.

Comment: spotted this in xubuntu 13.04 safe-upgrade worked :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, with regard to the comments: Sorry, you were right, I was *completely* mis-reading what apt-get was telling me (and I'm using the English version! :)).

After a little research, what you probably want to use is `aptitude safe-upgrade`, which *does* install new kernels. Really! I double checked! :)

You should probably prefer `aptitude` in general to `apt-get` anyway, unless you specifically need something in `apt-get`.

```
nknight@nkubuntu1004:~$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
Resolving dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-24{a} linux-headers-2.6.32-24-generic{a} linux-image-2.6.32-24-generic{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils base-files firefox firefox-branding firefox-gnome-support gdm google-chrome-stable 
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless 
  openjdk-6-jre-lib software-center thunderbird ureadahead xulrunner-1.9.2 
21 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 129MB of archives. After unpacking 188MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

Comment: Also cite the man page: It is sometimes necessary to remove one package in order to upgrade another; this command is not able to upgrade packages in such situations. Use the full-upgrade command to upgrade as many packages as possible.

Comment: aptitude will be removed from the default installation of future versions of both debian and ubuntu. Apt-get is again the preferred tool for installing packages

Comment: Yes, I didn't find aptitude in `12.04`. So I installed aptitude and ran `aptitude safe-upgrade`, it's also doing the same thing as apt-get upgrade. No kernel version are installed!(but I could see new kernel version available in synaptic package manager(gui)).

Answer (score 21):

you're looking for

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Using dist-upgrade can add or remove other packages, it's not limited to just the kernel. This can be an issue on a server if you're hosting for others. However in such a a case you probably want to use apt-pin anyways to prevent unintentional upgrades.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will install new packages while trying to resolve an upgrade, which is needed to get kernel updates when the kernel ABI changes (since it resolves to a different binary package name).

Answer (score 5):

if you want to install `aptitude` then please go ahead - but it has its dependencies and imho you can get away quite well without it - especially if you want to keep your *server* install lean(er).

When you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it tells you about packages that weren't upgraded in the following way:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

So, if you are connected using an ssh terminal, it's just a matter of copy+paste to enter the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

which upgrades just the packages that were kept back. Use `uname -r` to display the kernel version before and after the reboot (necessary to refresh the running kernel) and don't forget to run `purge-old-kernels` after the reboot.